# Concat array column from a group by in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following BigQuery table (It's external).

```yaml
organization: String
users: Array<String>
count_users: Integer
date: Date
```

I'm trying to do a `group by` over organization and `date` as

```sql
SELECT
  organization,
  EXTRACT(week FROM date) week_number,
  SUM(count_users) count_users,
  array_concat(users) users
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  organization,
  EXTRACT(week FROM date) week_number;
```

But I get the following error

SELECT list expression references column users which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [8:16].

I'm not sure what's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT
  organization,
  EXTRACT(week FROM date) week_number,
  SUM(count_users) count_users,
  array_concat_agg(users) users
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  organization,
  week_number
```